# Refreshing sorted table in React and state issue

Tags: reactjs

I tried to sort an array in React, but I don't know how to refresh it. If I set data in a state like this: (data: this.props.data) pagination isn't working. Why is that?

```
render() {
    let data = this.props.data;
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>iD</th>
                        <th>First name</th>
                        <th>Last name</th>
                        <th>Birth date</th>
                        <th onClick={() => {data.sort()}}>Company</th>
                        <th>Note</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {data.map((user) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={user.id}>
                                <td className="number">{user.id}</td>
                                <td className="firstname">{user.firstName}</td>
                                <td className="lastname">{user.lastName}</td>
                                <td className="date">{user.dateOfBirth}</td>
                                <td className="company">{user.company}</td>
                                <td className="note">{user.note}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the code below

```js
state = {
  //use constructor or es7
  data:this.props.data
}

_handleSort=()=>{
  /**
   * Define you short logic here.
   */
  let sortedDate = this.state.data.dateOfBirth.sort()
  this.setstate({
    data:sortedDate
  })
}
render() {
    let {data} = this.state;
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>iD</th>
                        <th>First name</th>
                        <th>Last name</th>
                        <th>Birth date</th>
                        <th onClick={() => {this._handleSort}>Company</th>
                        <th>Note</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {data.map((user) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={user.id}>
                                <td className="number">{user.id}</td>
                                <td className="firstname">{user.firstName}</td>
                                <td className="lastname">{user.lastName}</td>
                                <td className="date">{user.dateOfBirth}</td>
                                <td className="company">{user.company}</td>
                                <td className="note">{user.note}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that. Thanks for the simpliest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of fix this problem is sort array in parent component. 
Instesd of data.sort() you will call this.props.sort() property and your table component will be updated with sorted data.

```
render() {
    let data = this.props.data;
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>iD</th>
                        <th>First name</th>
                        <th>Last name</th>
                        <th>Birth date</th>
                        <th onClick={this.props.sort}>Company</th>
                        <th>Note</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {data.map((user) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={user.id}>
                                <td className="number">{user.id}</td>
                                <td className="firstname">{user.firstName}</td>
                                <td className="lastname">{user.lastName}</td>
                                <td className="date">{user.dateOfBirth}</td>
                                <td className="company">{user.company}</td>
                                <td className="note">{user.note}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Parent :

```
class Parent extends Component {
   constructor() {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
         data: ....
      }
  }

  sort = () => {
    this.setState({
        data: sortDataHere !!!!
    })
  }

  render() {
     return (
        <Table 
          data={this.state.data}
          sort={this.sort}
        />
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: Arguably this not the **best** solution as often the parent may not be an appropriate place for sort logic.  The standard solution is to separate state logic and presentation using something like `dispatch`. This is **a solution**, and fairly situational.

Comment: @vapurrmaid,  I do not see any mention of Redux in questing... My example shows way how components(stateful and stateless) should interact, but not shows Redux Best Practices.

Answer (score 0):

Your component isn't properly controlled, since you're just using a reference obtained from props, which doesn't trigger `render()`. Components should instead be controlled on either `state` or `props` to trigger `render()` changes.

Here's an example to demonstrate that this pattern doesn't work:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  render () {
    let text = this.props.data
    return (
      <div>
        {text}
        <button onClick={()=> (text='bye')}>
          Click Me
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example data='hello' />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

What you are trying to do is control the component. You have two main options:

**1) A stateful approach**:

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = { data: props.data }
}

render () {
  return (
    <th onClick={() => {sortTable.bind(this)}}>Company</th>
  )
}


sortTable () {
  let { data } = this.state
  // sort algorithm,
  this.setState({ data })
}
```

**2) A Stateless Pattern using props and something like Redux**

This is usually the preferred methodology as it keeps components purely as presentation without logic, which tend to be more reusable.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { data } = this.props
    return (
      <th onClick={() => this.props.sortData(data)}>Company</th>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    data: state.data
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    sortData: data => {
      dispatch({ type: SORT, payload: data })
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Example)
```

Then in a state reducer:

```
export default function (state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SORT:
      // transform the data
  }
}
```

I tried to keep this above example minimal, and as such it will not work as is. It purely demonstrates how the connected component might look. To fully use redux you need to setup your application with a `<Provider>` and  a `store`.